# Here.com API proper structure

Tags: here-api

When I run this code:

```
url = f"https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com//traffic/6.3/incidents.json?proximity=37.3541,-121.9552?apiKey={api_key}"

Scrape Here.com for any traffic incidents in the last 24 hours for the set proximity
res = requests.get(url)
date_requested = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
time_requested = time.strftime('%H:%M')
date_requested; time_requested #print date & time of request
```

I get this error:

```
<html><body><p>{"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"ApiKey is missing."}</p></body></html>
```

Can anyone tell me why?  I know the API key is valid because I generated a new one and cut and pasted it into the code above so it has to be the structure of my query, no?

I would really appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your URL part **replace second ? with &** as below-

```
url = f"https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com//traffic/6.3/incidents.json?proximity=37.3541,-121.9552&apiKey={}"
```

Comment: To splits the various parameter in the request we use & operator.

Comment: You can use only one "?" symbol in the URL. Everything behind is parameters and they should be concatenated with symbol "&".
To learn more about constructing proper URL, see this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL